# Twitter authentication fails

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to use the package twitteR for an analysis, but I came across a problem when I tried to authenticate with Twitter. Below are the error, and the code I use for the authentication. Anyone has any suggestions about a fix? thanks.

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object '.setDummyField' not found
```

This is the code I use to authenticate with Twitter.

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"

consumerKey <- "redacted"
consumerSecret <- "redacted"

twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret = consumerSecret,
                             requestURL = reqURL,
                             accessURL = accessURL,
                             authURL = authURL)

twitCred$handshake()
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

Answer (score 4):

OK. I resolved the problem. Apparently, the issue was that my R version was 3.0.0, but the twitteR package has been updated for version 3.0.1. An update of the version fixed the error.

Thanks,
Valentin